# How to write an output on csv file using python

Tags: python, export-to-csv

I have the following dataset stored in CSV file:

```
Name    Salary
John    50000
Eric    150000
Paul    100000
```

I want to get the median salary and output this value in the SAME csv file as follows:

```
Name    Salary  Median
John    50000   100000
Eric    150000  100000
Paul    100000  100000
```

Code:

```
import numpy as np 
from numpy import genfromtxt 
dataset = genfromtxt('C:\\Users\abc.csv',delimiter=',') 
x=dataset[2:,0] 
y=np.median(x)
```

Comment: what have you attempted to do before asking?

Comment: I'm able to read the dataset, and get the median value. I wrote the following code:

Comment: import numpy as np
from numpy import genfromtxt
dataset = genfromtxt('C:\\Users\abc.csv',delimiter=',')
x=dataset[2:,0]
x
y=np.median(x)

Comment: Please put your code, properly formatted, in your question.

Comment: any reason you're not using pandas?

Answer (score 1):

Now that you have `x` and `y`, you can just dump them with `np.savetxt`.

```
np.savetxt('C:\\Users\abc.csv', np.hstack((x[2:], y.reshape(-1, 1))) , delimiter=',')
```

Answer (score 0):

try pandas,In your case:

```
>>>files = 'example.csv'
>>>df = pd.read_csv(files)
>>>df = df.convert_objects(convert_numeric=True)
>>>df['Median'] = df['Salary'].median()
>>>df.to_csv(files)
```

more explanation

```
>>>files = 'example.csv'
>>>df = pd.read_csv(files)
>>>df = df.convert_objects(convert_numeric=True)
>>>df
   A   B   C   D
0  1   2   3   4
1  5   6   7   8
2  9  10  11  12
df['new']=13
>>>df
   A   B   C   D  new
0  1   2   3   4   13
1  5   6   7   8   13
2  9  10  11  12   13
>>>df['new'] = df['new'] +1
>>>df
   A   B   C   D  new
0  1   2   3   4   14
1  5   6   7   8   14
2  9  10  11  12   14
>>>df.insert(2,'win',22)
>>>df
   A   B  win   C   D  new
0  1   2   22   3   4   14
1  5   6   22   7   8   14
2  9  10   22  11  12   14
```

Comment: what question are you answering?

Comment: Thanks, it worked! however, one small issue: I want to add a column called remark which checks the median with salary. If median >= salary, remark ='YES'. Else: remark = 'NO'. I need following output:

Comment: Name Salary Median Remark
John 50000 100000 Yes
Eric 150000 100000 No
Paul 100000 100000 Yes

Comment: I wrote the following code, but got an error: if df['Salary'] <=df['median]: df['remark']='yes' else df['remark']='no'